# Netbeans - find files that doesn't contain specific text

Tags: regex, search, netbeans

Is it possible to find files by Netbeans function 'Find in Projects' (CTRL+SHIFT+F) with  regular expression that doesn't contain for example text 'mysql.php' ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible.

You can try the regular expression `"[^(mysql.php)]"` and it should work.

Comment: This didn't work for me. it found all lines of every file except the lines containing the string...

Answer (score 0):

As I could not achieve this in netbeans within a short time span, I did it whit a work around from the console (bash):

```
netbeans --open $(grep -IRiL "mysql.php" .)
```